# Using enable_shared_from_this in polymorphic inheritance with virtual destructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++14, shared-ptr, virtual-destructor

I have the following class structure for Managing callbacks with different prototypes:

```cpp
class MethodHandlerBase: public std::enable_shared_from_this<MethodHandlerBase>{
public:
    virtual void operator()(void* data) = 0;
    virtual ~MethodHandlerBase(){}
};
   
class MethodHandlerA: public MethodHandlerBase{
private:
    MethodHandlerACallback cb;
public:
    MethodHandlerA(MethodHandlerACallback cb): cb(cb){}
    virtual void operator()(void* data);
};
    
class MethodHandlerB: public MethodHandlerBase{
private:
    MethodHandlerBCallback cb;
public:
    MethodHandlerB(MethodHandlerBCallback cb): cb(cb){}
    virtual void operator()(void* data);
};
```

In some cases `MethodHandlerA` or `MethodHandlerB` might use `this` (wrapped in a shared_ptr) in a lambda expression passed to elsewhere, so I need to be sure that it is correctly deleted when needed. Therefore I added the `std::enable_shared_from_this<MethodHandlerBase>` inheritance to the base class.

But I read that you usally cannot use `std::enable_shared_from_this` via inheritance (apart from using a template, which actually would not really be inheritance anymore). In my understanding this is due to the possible wrongly destruction of the instance. In this case I would assume my code would work properly since it uses a virtual destructor (which is needed anyway).

So am I right with my theory or is there something else going on about `std::enable_shared_from_this` inheritance that I did not understand?

**EDIT**:

To add a short examples of what I plan to use it like:

From inside the class:

```cpp
void MethodHandlerB::operator()(void* data){
    std::shared_ptr<MethodHandlerB> thisPtr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<MethodHandlerB>(this->shared_from_this());
    putLamdaToSomeGlobalEventThing([thisPtr](){
        thisPtr->doSomething();
    });
}
```

and from outside

```
std::vector<MethodHandlerBase> vec{std::make_shared<MethodHandlerB>()};
```

Comment: Minor comment.  `enabled_shared_from_this` must be publicly visible for it to work.  Other than that, what you have above should work, at least with this limited example.

Comment: If you put `this` into a lambda capture, it doesn't create a `std::shared_ptr` of `this` automatically - you need to do this explicitly. Also, it's unclear to me what you mean by "I read that you usally cannot use `std::enable_shared_from_this` via inheritance". It is meant to be a base class, so must use it through inheritance?!

Comment: @DaveS yeah thanks. I copied this together from struct MethodHandlerBase: std::enable_shared_from_this<MethodHandlerBase>` but when changed to class I forgot to add `public`. Edited the question.

Comment: So the question remains:  What do you think won't work?  What you have above will work.

Comment: @DaveS I added to examples of how I would like to use the class (its shared_ptr). In my opinion this should properly work but I am not sure about that.

Comment: @lubgr I added to examples of how I would like to use the class (its shared_ptr). In my opinion this should properly work but I am not sure about that.

Comment: `std::enable_shared_from_this` on base class doesn't mace seance (especially it suppose to be pure abstract). From my experience best practice is to use `std::enable_shared_from_this` on classes which are final.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr<MethodHandlerB> thisPtr(this);` is going to be a problem, because there will be two different shared_ptr that manage the object.  You'll want to use [shared_from_this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) instead.

Comment: @Eljay ah thanks, I've assumed that there would be an overload for `shared_ptr<enable_shared_from_this>::shared_ptr(enable_shared_from_this* ptr)`. So now I am using: `std::shared_ptr<MethodHandlerB> thisPtr = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<MethodHandlerB>(this->shared_from_this());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some minor points:

- You could move the shared pointer into the lambda to avoid an atomic increment and decrement
- No need to use a dynamic pointer cast since you know for sure the dynamic type (plus you don't check the result is not empty anyway!)

```
void MethodHandlerB::operator()(void* data){
    auto thisPtr = std::static_pointer_cast<MethodHandlerB>(this->shared_from_this());
    putLamdaToSomeGlobalEventThing([thisPtr = std::move(thisPtr)](){
        thisPtr->doSomething();
    });
}
```

- Alternatively, you could use separate captures for `this` and the shared pointer, which avoids the cast altogether:

```
void MethodHandlerB::operator()(void* data){
    putLamdaToSomeGlobalEventThing([this, thisPtr = shared_from_this()](){
        doSomething();
    });
}
```

---

Edit: as one of the comments points out, if you don't use `shared_from_this()` directly on the base class, you're better off just deriving from `enable_shared_from_this` in the derived classes. You can do this because C++ supports multiple inheritence.

```
class MethodHandlerBase {
public:
    virtual void operator()(void* data) = 0;
    virtual ~MethodHandlerBase(){}
};
   
class MethodHandlerA: 
    public MethodHandlerBase,
    public std::enable_shared_from_this<MethodHandlerA>
{
private:
    MethodHandlerACallback cb;
public:
    MethodHandlerA(MethodHandlerACallback cb): cb(cb){}
    virtual void operator()(void* data);
};

void MethodHandlerA::operator()(void* data){
    putLamdaToSomeGlobalEventThing([self = shared_from_this()](){
        self->doSomething();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a little helper class

```
  template <class Base, class Derived>
  struct enable_shared : public Base
  {   
      std::shared_ptr<Derived> shared_from_this()
      {   
          return std::static_pointer_cast<Derived>(
                                          Base::shared_from_this());
      };
  };
```

Now you can use `shared_from_this` freely in all these classes. and it will return the correct type:

```
class Base : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Base> ...;
class Derived : public enable_shared<Base, Derived> ...;
class MoreDerived : public enable_shared<Derived, MoreDerived> ...;
```

By the way, if you use `std::make_shared`, then a virtual destructor is *not* needed, because the shared pointer is created with the right deleter for the most derive type. It is probably a good idea to define one anyway, just to be on the safe size. (Or maybe not.)